# Change width of date-picker in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, datepicker

I want to change the width of the horizontal line on the date-picker. I tried setting the style of the div, adding it into the `app-global-date-picker` tag and tried putting it into the css page but nothing has worked so far

```
<div style="text-align: center" class="p-1">
    <app-global-date-picker
           idPrefix="chequeDate"
           inputLabel="BI.STOP_CHEQUE_DATE"
           inputError="BI.STOP_CHEQUE_DATE_ALERT"
           [control]="stopChequeForm.controls.chequeDate"
           style="width: 460px !important"
   ></app-global-date-picker>
```

I want the line to look like this:

[image]

Comment: It would be easier to have a look at the problem if you provided a
[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
You can set one up over at [stackblitz](https://www.stackblitz.com)

Comment: You modified the `style` of `app-global-date-picker`, which is not going to change the style of any elements inside that components template.

Comment: @MikeS. I also tried putting the style into the div tag but that also didn't change the date-picker. Where do I need to put the style?

Comment: You need to target a class or the id of that horizontal line and apply your styles on that. You can inspect the element in the console for that information (which is why a reproducer would be great)